# Read values from a text files column using entered table header

Tags: c++, file

Not sure if I have worded this right but here it goes..

I have read a text file and it outputs as follows:

```
    C14 C16 C18 C20 C22 C24 C27 C30 C35 C40 C45 C50 D30 D35 D40 D50 D60 D70
ft0k    8   10  11  12  13  14  16  18  21  24  27  30  18  21  24  30  36  42
fc0k    16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  25  26  27  29  23  25  26  29  32  34
density 290 310 320 330 340 350 370 380 400 420 440 460 530 560 590 650 700 900
```

the I have `cin>>woodType;`

If the user enters C14 I want it to get the values 8, 16, 290
or if they enter C22 I want 12, 19, 330.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

I am very new to C++ and I am not sure where to start.

Thanks

EDIT------ additional code

this gets the file data

```
std::ifstream ifs ("strength_classes.txt", std::ifstream::in);

char c = ifs.get();


while (ifs.good()) {
    std::cout << c;
    c = ifs.get();
}

ifs.close();
```

this is run in the command line which grabs the value the user enters:

```
    cout << "CHOOSE A WOOD TYPE BY TYPING THE LETTER OF A WOOD TYPE" << endl<< endl;
cout << "Poplar and softwood species" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------"<< endl;
cout << "A = C14" << setw(12) << "B = C16" << setw(12) << "C = C18" << endl
<< "D = C20" << setw(12) << "E = C22" << setw(12) << "F = C24" << endl
<< "G = C27" << setw(12) << "H = C30" << setw(12) << "I = C35" << endl
<< "J = C40" << setw(12) << "K = C45" << setw(12) << "L = C50" << endl;
cout << " "<<endl;
cout << "Hardwood species" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------"<< endl;
cout << "M = D30" << setw(12) << "N = D35" << setw(12) << "O = D40" << endl
<< "P = D50" << setw(12) << "Q = D60" << setw(12) << "R = D70" << endl;
cout << " "<<endl;

cin>>woodType;
cout << "You choose woodtype" << setw(2) << chosenwood(woodType) << endl;
```

which runs this function:

while (woodType != 'A' && woodType != 'a' && woodType != 'B' && woodType != 'b' && woodType != 'C' && woodType != 'c' &&
        woodType != 'D' && woodType != 'd' && woodType != 'E' && woodType != 'e' && woodType != 'F' && woodType != 'f' && 
        woodType != 'G' && woodType != 'g' && woodType != 'H' && woodType != 'h' && woodType != 'I' && woodType != 'i' && 
        woodType != 'J' && woodType != 'j' && woodType != 'K' && woodType != 'k' && woodType != 'L' && woodType != 'l' &&
        woodType != 'M' && woodType != 'm' && woodType != 'N' && woodType != 'n' && woodType != 'O' && woodType != 'o' && 
        woodType != 'P' && woodType != 'p' && woodType != 'Q' && woodType != 'q' && woodType != 'R' && woodType != 'r'  ) 
    {
    cout << "THAT IS NOT ONE OF THE CHOICES! TRY AGAIN" <

```
if(woodType=='A');

cin>>woodType;
}
return woodType;
```

Comment: Looks like this table [Wood Type Density](http://books.google.ca/books?id=1FZ0C2QI6poC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=C14+C16+C18+C20+C22+C24+C27+C30+C35+C40+C45+C50+D30+D35+D40+D50+D60+D70&source=bl&ots=5lsWROfuhy&sig=11UqOd1aAT2UoSYnu8OpJidqMUw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UWWnUrz4CcreoAS5n4HgDA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=C14%20C16%20C18%20C20%20C22%20C24%20C27%20C30%20C35%20C40%20C45%20C50%20D30%20D35%20D40%20D50%20D60%20D70&f=false). Can you show what you have tried so far? Looks like a simple multi-dimensional array should do the trick.

Comment: Yes that is the table, ok I will edit the answer and paste the relevant code @KingChicken

Answer (score 0):

So you have already read in the data?  What kind of data structure have you put it into?  In general, you will need to iterate over the data (looking for the key, e.g. "C14"), and once you find it, retrieve the dependent data.

E.g. if you have the data like:

```
class WoodData {
public:
   string name;
   int ft0k;
   int fc0k;
   int density;
};
```

and have it in a list like:

```
std::list<WoodData> woodTypes;
```

then you would iterate over the list like:

```
auto iterWood = std::find_if( woodTypes.begin(), woodTypes.end(), [&woodType](const WoodData& aWood) {
                        return aWood.name == woodType; }
                         );
if (iterWood != woodTypes.end() ) { /* do your thing */ }
```

(This is depends upon a compiler that supports lambdas, i.e. C++11.)